# What happens to the original .h file when using autotools?

Tags: c, header-files, autotools

I'm creating a shell in C. The .tar.gz file that I created works perfectly fine. However when I unzip this, the original header file that I used in generating said file is changed to contain code used by autotools. Is there a way to preserve the original .h file?

For reference, this is my configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([program_name], 1.0)  
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE  
AC_PROG_CC  
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([shell.h])  
AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)  
AC_OUTPUT
```

The Makefile.am Program is:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = shell  
shell_SOURCES = main.c functions.c
```

I was hoping that when I cat shell.h I would see the original #include and #define 's that I made. However it just has the typical autotools #defines about package and version no.

Any help in this, as well as explaining what's actually happening here would be greatly appreciated, so I don't do this again.

Answer (score 1):

`AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` ([documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.66/html_node/Configuration-Headers.html)) outputs an Autoconf-generated header file with information about the package and the environment used to compile it.

Usually this file is called `config.h` but you seem to have called it `shell.h` which overwrote another `shell.h` file that you created manually, I'm guessing?

If that's the case, the solution would be to use a different name in `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS`.

Comment: ... or maybe just omit `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS`.  It sounds like the OP may have altogether the wrong idea about what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

As @ptomato already observed, `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` is for requesting that the `configure` script should create a header file for you when it runs, in which it defines macros conveying various information that it has gleaned, such as the results of various tests.  The macro argument specifies the name this generated file should have.  This is an alternative to all that information being passed to compilation commands on the command line.  It has nothing to do with naming a header file provided among the sources, and it will certainly cause any such header to be replaced.  It is also useless if your sources do not `#include` the designated header.

It's unclear whether you want such a configuration header, but if `shell.h` is a header you have provided, and you do not want `configure` to overwrite it, then do not specify its name to `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS`.  You can probably do without `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` altogether, though I personally like it because using it makes the ultimate `make` output easier to read.  If you continue to use it then you need to choose a different name (such as the conventional `config.h`), and you need to have *all* your C sources `#include` that header before they do anything else.

To inform Automake of a header provided among the sources that is not ultimately installed, just list it among the `_SOURCES` of at least one target.  Automake knows not to try to compile headers, but listing them among your sources will ensure that they get packaged into distribution tarballs produced via `make dist`.  There are alternatives, such as listing such headers in `EXTRA_DIST`, but they are less conventional.